How to volume existing db in docker container?
I have a Django project. I've created a PostgreSQL database and populate it with data. How I need to mount this database inside docker container, but I get an error after request ProgrammingError at /api/v1/movies/ relation "content.film_work" does not exist, that tells that database is empty. When I run psql -U app -d movies_database in the terminal I get the database with all data, but when I run docker exec -it <container_id> sh and then psql -U app -d movies_database I do get that movies_database is empty. Seems like I cannot volume an existing database inside docker container. What's wrong? I'm using PostgreSQL 16.3 (psql (PostgreSQL) 16.3).
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8' 

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./movies_admin:/movies_admin"
    env_file:
      - "movies_admin/config/.env"
    depends_on:
      - database
      - elasticsearch
  
  database:

    image: postgres:16

    environment:
    
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_database
      - POSTGRES_USER=app
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123qwe
    
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - "./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
      - "./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - "./movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/admin:/etc/nginx/movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/admin"
      - "./movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/rest_framework:/etc/nginx/movies_admin/movies_admin/staticfiles/rest_framework"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django
  
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.13.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx200m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine

RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev linux-headers pcre-dev

WORKDIR /movies_admin

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

EXPOSE 8000

COPY movies_admin .

RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

CMD [ "uwsgi", "--ini", "/movies_admin/uwsgi.ini" ]

components/database.py
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': '123qwe',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', 'database'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public,content'
        }
    }
} 



Extract a [mcve]. In particular, I wonder if this is due to mounting a volume as data storage into the DB container. Also, I'm not sure if your issue isn't caused by name resolution within the setup, but there's too little detail to tell.
